# mysql query to get unique missing values with comparing 2 tables

Tags: mysql

master table1 Name: master_port
port_name (column name)
ABC
SDF
EFR
GTY
FGH
KIU
NMU
LOI
KUJ
SEC
FFR
ETY

[image: table2&3 details]

I need port list from table2 and table3(both orgin_port and destination_port) thats not found in the master table1 Name: master_port
how do i get those using mysql query
please help me to resole this

Comment: can you explain more your output ?

Comment: master table contain value with mixed origin and destination port, 
step1 compare table1 origin port with master table get the new port list from table1 
step2 compare table1 destination port with master table get the new port list from table1
step3 compare table2 origin port with master table get the new port list from table2 
step4 compare table2 destination port with master table get the new port list from table2
step5 combine all the result and shown as a single output
[ new port list :- that's not found in the master table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT tab.port FROM
(SELECT origin_port AS port FROM location1
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT destination_port AS port FROM  location1
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT origin_port AS port FROM sender2
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT destination_port AS port FROM  sender2) tab
WHERE tab.port NOT IN 
(SELECT port_name FROM master_port);
```

This return origin and destination port in both tables location1 and sender2 which are not found in master_port

Comment: Thanks for your reply